# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (applyHooks.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

[image]

Why is it appearing? I installed all dependencies and now I'm stuck here.

Comment: Welcome Syed, you should put code examples and error messages directly in the question so that it's easier for people to see them. Adding more context would also make it more likely for someone to understand and answer your question.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: However, the problem seems to be that you are passing `undefined` to the module somehow (`q[i]` is `undefined`). Since we don't know your code, there isn't anything we can do to help.

Comment: Can you log the q variable?

Answer (score 0):

**[TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError)**: The *TypeError* object represents an error when a value is not of the expected type.

You are trying to access zeroth index of variable `pair` which is `undefined`. `pair` is assigned a value at index `i` of an array `q`. Due to limited information provided in question and value of `q` is not provided thus it's difficult to provide solution correctly.

**[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)**: The global *undefined* property represents the primitive value `undefined`. It is one of JavaScript's primitive types.

Since `undefined` object is not a string or an array thus accessing it's zeroth index gives an error. Value of `pair` is `undefined` as array `q` might be having an array like `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Would request you to check value of `q` and then value of `pair` before performing any operation on these variable.

How an array like `[undefined, undefined, ...]` is formed:

```
var b;  // Since b is not assigned any value thus it's undefined
var q = [];
q.push(b);   // Repeat this few more time and whole array of [undefined, undefined, ...] will be created with length > 0
```

Would recommend to do go through [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) once before using it's features to avoid errors and using JavaScript at best.

Comment: *"Since undefined object is not a string or an array thus accessing it's zeroth index gives an error. "* That's not quite right. `undefined` is **not** an object, which is why the error is thrown. `undefined` cannot be converted to an object an thus its `i` property cannot be accessed. Compare that to primitive values who can be converted to objects: `true.foo // no error`.

Comment: Thanks, Navin I will check